# Parse HTML user input

Tags: php, html, validation, parsing, user-generated-content

Let's say I have a string from the user (`$input`). I can go and [strip tags](http://www.php.net/strip_tags), to allow only allowed tags in. I can convert to text with `htmlspecialchars()`. I can even replace all tags I don't want with text.

```
function html($input) {
    $input = '<bl>'.htmlspecialchars($input).'</bl>'; // bl is a custom tag that I style (stands for block)
    global $open;
    $open = []; //Array of open tags
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++) {
        if (!in_array('code', $open) && !in_array('codebl', $open)) { //If we are parsing
            $input = preg_replace_callback('#^(.{'.$i.'})&lt;(em|i|del|sub|sup|sml|code|kbd|pre|codebl|quote|bl|sbl)&gt;\s*#s', function($match) {
                global $open; //...then add new tags to the array
                array_push($open,$match[2]);
                return $match[1].'<'.$match[2].'>'; //And replace them
            }, $input);
            $input = preg_replace_callback('#^(.{'.$i.'})(https?):\/\/([^\s"\(\)<>]+)#', function($m) {
                return $m[1].'<a href="'.$m[2].'://'.$m[3].'" target="_blank">'.$m[3].'</a>';
            }, $input, -1, $num); //Simple linking
            $i += $num * 9;
            $input = preg_replace_callback('#^(.{'.$i.'})\n\n#', function($m) {
                return $m[1].'</bl><bl>';
            }, $input); // More of this bl element
        }
        if (end($open)) { //Close tags
            $input = preg_replace_callback('#^(.{'.$i.'})&lt;/('.end($open).')&gt;#s', function($match) {
                global $open;
                array_pop($open);
                return trim($match[1]).'</'.$match[2].'>';
            }, $input);
        }
    }
    while ($open) { //Handle unclosed tags
        $input .= '</'.end($open).'>';
        array_pop($open);
    }
    return $input;
}
```

The problem is that after that, there is no way to write literally `&lt;i&lgt;&lt;/i&gt;`, because it will be automatically parsed into either `<i></i>` (if you write `<i></i>`), or `&amplt;i&ampgt;&amplt;/i&ampgt;` (if you write `&lt;i&gt;&lt;/i&gt;`). I want the user to be able to enter `&lt;` (or any other HTML entity) and get `&lt;` back. If I just send it straight to the browser unparsed, it would (obviously) be vulnerable to whatever sorcery the hackers are trying (and I'm letting) to (be) put on my site. So, **How can I let the user use any of the pre-defined set of HTML tags, while still letting them use html entities?**

Comment: use HTMLPurifier instead. striptags is a nuclear bomb, htmlpurifier can be a scalpel (but does support nukes as well).

Comment: See this links

[stackoverflow.com][1]


[stackoverflow.com][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: @Mortzea You links are so ugly… Ok, they are helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I eventually used:

```
function html($input) {
    $input = preg_replace(["#&([^A-z])#","#<([^A-z/])#","#&$#","#<$#"], ['&amp;$1','&lt;$1','&amp;','&lt;'], $input); //Fix single "<"s and "&"s
    $open = []; //Array of open tags
    $close = false; //Is the current tag a close tag?
    for ($i = 0; $i <= strlen($input); $i++) { //Start the loop
        if ($tag) { //Are we in a tag?
            if (preg_match("/[^a-z]/", $input[$i])) { //The tag has ended
                if ($close) {
                    $close = false;
                    $sPos = strrpos(substr($input,0,$i), '<') + 2; //start position of tag
                    $tag = substr($input,$sPos,$i-$sPos); //tag name
                    if (end($open) == $tag) {
                        array_pop($open); //Good, it's a valid XML closing
                    } else {
                        $input = substr($input, 0, $sPos-2) . '&lt;/' . $tag . substr($input, $i); //BAD! Convert tag to text (open tag will be handled later)
                    }
                } else {
                    $sPos = strrpos(substr($input,0,$i), '<') + 1; //start position of tag
                    $tag = substr($input,$sPos,$i-$sPos); //tag name
                    if (in_array($tag, ['em','i','del','sub','sup','sml','code','kbd','pre','codebl','bl','sbl'])) { //Is it an acceptable tag?
                        array_push($open, $tag); //Add it to the array
                        $j = $i + 1;
                        while (preg_match("/\s/", $input[$j])) { //Get rid of whitespace
                            $j++;
                        }
                        $input = substr($input, 0, $sPos - 1) . '<' . $tag . '>' . substr($input, $j); //Seems legit
                    } else {
                        $input = substr($input, 0, $sPos - 1) . '&lt;' . $tag . substr($input, $i); //BAD! Convert tag to text
                    }
                }
                $tag = false;
            }
        } else if (!in_array('code', $open) && !in_array('codebl', $open) && !in_array('pre', $open)) { //Standard parsing of text
            if ($input[$i] == '<') { //Is it a tag?
                $tag = true;
                if ($input[$i+1] == '/') { //Is it a close tag?
                    $i++;
                    $close = true;
                }
            } else if (substr($input, $i, 4) == 'http') { //Link
                if (preg_match('#^.{'.$i.'}(https?):\/\/([^\s"\(\)<>]+)#', $input, $m)) {
                    $insert = '<a href="'.$m[1].'://'.$m[2].'" target="_blank">'.$m[2].'</a>';
                    $input = substr($input, 0, $i) . $insert . substr($input, $i + strlen($m[1].'://'.$m[2]));
                    $i += strlen($insert);
                }
            } else if ($input[$i] == "\n" && $input[$i+1] == "\n") { //Insert <bl> tag? (I use this to separate sections of text)
                $input = substr($input, 0, $i + 1) . '</bl><bl>' . substr($input, $i + 1);
            }
        } else { // We're in a code tag
            if (substr($input, $i+1, strlen(end($open)) + 3) == '</'.current($open).'>') {
                array_pop($open);
                $i += 2;
            } elseif ($input[$i] == '<') {
                $input = substr($input, 0, $i) . '&lt;' . substr($input, $i + 1);
                $i += 3; //Code tags have raw text
            } elseif (in_array('code', $open) && $input[$i] == "\n") { //No linebreaks are allowed in inline tags, convert to <codebl>
                $open[count($open) - 1] = 'codebl';
                $input = substr($input, 0, strrpos($input,'<code>')) . '<codebl>' . substr($input, strrpos($input,'<code>') + 6, strpos(substr($input, strrpos($input,'<code>')),'</code>') - 6) . '</codebl>' . substr($input, strpos(substr($input, strrpos($input,'<code>')),'</code>') + strrpos($input,'<code>') + 7);
                $i += 4;
            }
        }
    }
    while ($open) { //Handle open tags
        $input .= '</'.end($open).'>';
        array_pop($open);
    }
    return '<bl>'.$input.'</bl>';
}
```

I know it's a bit more risky, but you can first assume the input's good, then filter out the stuff explicitly found as bad.

Comment: Why? Mostly I just hate libs. :P DIE JQUERY!