# How to validate text from Summernote - Php

Tags: php, xss, code-injection, summernote

I have some questions about how to avoid Xss injection and remove tags:

I'm using sommernote and I want to allow some tags like `<br>, <p>, <strong>, etc.`. I could use the function strip_tags() but if someone writes the symbol greater (>) or less (<), for instance:

(4 > 5).

This is removed and I want to keep it.

Besides, I need to know the correct length of the text that was entered because I don't want to allow more than N characters, let's say no more than 300 characters. In order to get this I would use strip_tags() but the string is truncated as I mentioned before. How can i do this?

Obviously, I want to avoid XSS injection so I would use `htmlentities(strip_tags(string), ENT_QUOTES)` to save in DB and when I want to show the content in the main page i would use html_entity_decode(string), is that enough to avoid it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest using [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). When implementing security measures, you'll be better off using an extensive and well tested library instead of creating something on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use strip_tags! If a user tries to enter something like `The bob said <the-secret>`, it will be stripped! `htmlentities` is unnecessary. You want [`htmlspecialchars`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

```
$input = "<script>alert('ur screwed')</script>";
echo htmlspecialchars($input);
```

Returns `&lt;script&gt;alert('ur screwed')&lt;/script&gt;`. Decode with [`htmlspecialchars_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php).

Comment: Actually, I wanted to say htmlspecialchars(), I got confused. My question is if i use htmlspecialchars_decode() to show in the main page I would be written the original sentence, in this case: `<script>alert('ur screwed')</script>` or I'm wrong?

Comment: You don't need to decode (normally). Store as written in DB, when it comes out do a htmlspecialchars.

Comment: Ok, but i would like to show if someone writes `<pr>something</p>` because I'm using sommernote, if I save with htmlspecialchars(), I'll have to show with htmlspecialchars_decode() so that it can be pretty on the browser.

Comment: That will be an additional complication **after** you encode the data. Don't encode the data before going into the DB, do it after. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21792609/parse-html-user-input) might help (and be confusing).